# batch loop through C:\Users using variable set as wild card

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, find, wildcard

I have a list of computer names in a network (hosts.txt), only certain users on the network need some software installing on their PC's. I always know their names not the logons details.

E.g

I know a user has a name of Adam Mint and I want to know what computer he uses on the LAN, I don't know his logon but do know, via naming convention, that his log is something like **amint2**, **mintya** or **amint** etc.

So with a list of computers I want to search through C:\users using a wild card of *mint to find what computers he has ever logged on to. From there I know the computers etc need some software installing for that user. I have tried to put some code together but I'm missing something. Please could some one show me where I am going wrong? Thanks

```
set /p search=Input search string...

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0hosts.txt") do (
if exist "\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*" echo "%search% string was found in users folder on %%A"  
)
```

*update* Working nicely so far, help appreciated. I was wondering if I could further enhance it. I'm finding the same user may have logged to many of the PC's so I have manually searched through the modified dates of the folders to see which is most current (took ages); usually identifying actual PC in use. Can I add some code to expand the \%%A\C$\Users*%search%*" section to report the full path and then echo the modified date of the profile folder.

e.g the output at the minute is...

```
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098763"
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098463"
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098763"
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098793"
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098713"
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098703"
```

..could it in fact include

```
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098763 last used 09/11/16"
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098463 last used 09/11/15"
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098763 last used 12/02/14"
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098793 last used 01/01/14"
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098713 last used 01/11/13"
"amint string was found in users folder on PCSG-098703 last used 15/11/12"
```

thank you ...

Comment: Remove the `&&`... And I think you should use search pattern `*%search%*`, according to your examples...

Comment: Silly me, so close, thanks for making it work!. Works great will be very handy. Have edited original question with working code if it's ever of use to  some one else. :-)

Comment: If you are connecting to the administrative share it should be `\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*`

Comment: It's not a good idea to implement the solution in the question, it would be better to post it as an answer (remember you can answer your own question and even accept your own answer then)...

Comment: I've updated the original post with some other asks, is that okay or should I open a brand new question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p search=Input search string... 

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0hosts.txt") do ( if exist "\\%%A\C$\Users\*%search%*" echo "%search% string was found in users folder on %%A" )
```

As suggested here is the correct answer after the comments.